# Count the total number of records in the database but return only X records

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, postgresql

We are shifiting one of our applications from PostGreSQL to MySQL. We have the following query in **PostGres** -

```
SELECT 
      idrte
    , left_name
    , gacodemun
    , clsrte
    , speed
    , speed_override
    , ST_AsGeoJSON(geometry) AS geometry
    , count(idrte) OVER() AS total 
FROM 
    aq_routes 
WHERE 
    ST_CONTAINS(
        GeomFromText(
            'Polygon(($geom))'
        ),geometry) 
GROUP BY 
      idrte
    , left_name
    , gacodemun
    , clsrte
    , speed
    , speed_override
    , geometry 
ORDER BY left_name 
LIMIT 150;
```

We are trying to port this query to **MySQL** ad have come up with this -

```
SELECT 
     id AS id
   , left_name AS left_name
   , left_locality AS left_locality
   , class AS class
   , speed AS speed
   , speed_override AS speed_override
   , AsWKB(Geom) AS geom
   , count(id) AS total 
FROM road_segments 
WHERE 
   CONTAINS(
       GeomFromText(
           'Polygon(($geom))'
       ),geom) 
GROUP BY 
      id
    , left_name
    , class
    , speed
    , speed_override
    , geom 
ORDER BY left_name 
LIMIT 150;
```

There are some field changes, but on the whole the intended functionality is to be the same.

You'll notice the call the `OVER()` in the PostGreSQL. The table we are querying has a lot of data. So to the user, we display only 150 records but tell him the count of all the records. With PostGres this was possible through a single call but we don't have `OVER()` function in MySQL.

What other alternatives do we have other than querying the database a second time. A second query to the database is increasing the response time by at least 15 seconds and sometimes even timing out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use `FOUND_ROWS()` and `CALC_FOUND_ROWS()`.  You can review the documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows).

The basic idea is:

```
select CALC_FOUND_ROWS id, . . .
. . .
```

Then use the function `FOUND_ROWS()` to return the value to the application.

Unfortunately, to get this value as a column value, I think you would need to run the query twice, essentially:

```
select . . ., x.cnt
from . . . cross join
     (select count(*) as cnt from <your query here>) x
. . .
```

Comment: `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ...` One way to get the result in one query (with a client that supports multiple result sets) is to wrap both queries in a stored proc.  I have one I use that accepts "rows per page" and "page number," as arguments, does the math for you so that it sets limit and offset, and returns a 2nd resultset with the total rows, and does some cute sugary calculations to tell the app what "page number" is first (always 1 of course), previous, current, next, and last.